# javafx combobox editable autocomplete

Tags: java, javafx, controlsfx

I have created a combo box which adds list of entries. I have made this combo box as editable and autocomplete. The issue is as follows

1)I selected the Arial value from the dropdown using mouseclick.

2)After that I typed black and from the result list I selected Arial Black using enter button.

3)Then again I clicked on Arial value using mouseclick ,the Arial value gets selected but along with it the result List is shown again even though i selected the value.

I want to hide the result list on click of mouse selection value. The result list is nothing but ComboBoxPopupControl. I tried using dispose method but it dint worked. Can anyone suggest the code on click of comboBox.setOnAction.

[image]

Here is the code

```
java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.controlsfx.control.textfield.TextFields;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.event.EventType;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TestAutoTextSearch_bkp extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        launch();

    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        List<String> countries = new ArrayList<>();
        countries.add("Arial");
        countries.add("Arial Black");
        countries.add("Arial Narrow");


        ComboBox<String> comboBox = new ComboBox();
        comboBox.getItems().addAll(countries);
        ComboBox<String> comboBox1 = new ComboBox();

        comboBox.setEditable(true);
        comboBox.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);






        comboBox.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                //Tried dispose method here but dint worked[![enter image description here][1]][1]


            }
        });

        comboBox.getEditor().setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(KeyEvent ke) {
                 KeyCode kc = ke.getCode();
                System.out.println("Inside Key Press");
                 if ((kc.isLetterKey())||kc.isArrowKey()||kc.equals(KeyCode.BACK_SPACE)) {
                      TextFields.bindAutoCompletion(comboBox.getEditor(), comboBox.getItems());


            }}
        });








        Group root = new Group();
        root.getChildren().add(comboBox);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

        comboBox.setMinWidth(comboBox.getWidth());
        comboBox.setPrefWidth(comboBox.getWidth());

    }

}
```

Comment: If you mouse click `Arial Black` and then `Arial`, it happens. I am guessing that it's trying to show you different options as if you are typing in the field.

Comment: Am I the only one that tried to drag the little window out of the way?

Answer (score 1):

You can try solution from small utility library [jalvafx](https://github.com/jalva-top/jalvafx)

```
List<String> items = Arrays.asList("Mercury", 
                                   "Venus", 
                                   "Earth", 
                                   "Mars", 
                                   "Jupiter", 
                                   "Saturn", 
                                   "Neptune");

ComboBoxCustomizer.create(comboBox)
                  .autocompleted(items)
                  .customize();
```

By default, double click to clear value.

There are some other usefull features. You can add extra columns or glyphs, single out specific items, change items default toString representation ...

```
ComboBoxCustomizer.create(comboBox)
                  .autocompleted(items)
                  .overrideToString(o -> "planet: " + o)
                  .multyColumn(o -> Arrays.asList("column 2", "column 3"))
                  .emphasized(o -> o.endsWith("s"))
                  .customize();
```

Comment: advertising a library, yours? Anyways, Please don't post identical answers  to multiple questions. Post one good answer, then vote/flag to close the other questions as duplicates. If the questions are not duplicates, _tailor your answers to the question_.

Comment: Thank you for advising me. Library is mine. I use it in my applications. It is free, so I do not have any profits.